# How to get value from correlated value in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am capturing uuid details in one correlation value C_uuid_details.(passing the C_uuid_details instance with threadnum funtion for picking unique id every time)

I need to capture "last action date" value from the "C_uuid_details".

if "last action date" value is there in "C_uuid_details" passing in the script, then i should capture that value.

if "last action date" value is not there in "C_uuid_details" passing in the script, then i should pass "null" value in it.

can anyone help me in it?

Answer (score 0):

We cannot suggest anything regarding how to extract the "last action date" because we don't know how does it look like.

Be informed that any [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) like [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) can be applied to a JMeter Variable and it's possible to supply a default value if the search pattern is not present:

[image]

If none of the Post-Processors is able to fetch the "last action date" from the variable you can go for a suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223).

Pseudo-code would be something like:

```
if (vars.get('C_uuid_details').contains('last action date')) {
    vars.put('some-variable', 'your logic to extract last action date here')
} else {
    vars.put('some-variable', 'null')
}
```

In the above example `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) article for more details.